# VBA variable within If...Then won't increment

Tags: vba, excel

Updated - still not solved

**Modul**

```
Public igOneVar As Integer 

Sub ShowUserForm1() 

    UserForm1.Show 

End Sub
```

**Forms**

```
Private Sub Name_Click() 

Dim laufVar As Integer 

MsgBox "start " & igOneVar 

If ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = 2 Then 
    For laufVar = 8 To 250 
        If ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = 2 Then 
            ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = "If" 
            Exit For 
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = 3 Then 
            ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = "ElseIf" 
            igOneVar = igOneVar + 1 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next laufVar 
End If 

MsgBox "end " & igOneVar 

Unload UserForm1 

End Sub
```

So I have a button, which opens a Userform (**Modul**), which has a cmdButton in it. If I click on the cmdButton(Name_Click), it'll start some code(**Forms**). But it won't store the incremented variable. The variable in `MsgBox "start " & igOneVar` is 0 and stays at 0.

Comment: if this condition is true `ElseIf ... Then` then `igOneVar` can changed only to `igOneVar = 1` since you have `Exit For`

Comment: But I need him to stop at this point. Any options to increment the variable within my ElseIf?

Comment: it's already increments. but since you have `Exit For`, `igOneVar` can be incremented only once

Comment: The problem is, if I run the procedure a 2nd, 3rd, nth time, it'll always stay at 1. So it does increment within my ElseIf, but it won't store the new value at the top. I need him to update my igOneVar = 0 to igOneVar = 1 after my first ElseIf and to igOneVar = 2 after I run the procedure a 2nd time.

Comment: change `Dim igOneVar as Integer` to `Static igOneVar As Integer` and remove `igOneVar = 0`. Let me know if it helps

Comment: changed it to `Static igOneVar as Integer` but it still stays at one. I also removed `igOneVar = 0`

Comment: Put `Dim igOneVar As Integer` at the top of your code above the Private Sub to make it a global variable. and remove `igOneVar = 0`

Comment: Didn't work. @PortlandRunner

Comment: Should work just fine: `Dim igOneVar As Integer

Private Sub test()
    igOneVar = igOneVar + 1
    MsgBox (igOneVar)
End Sub` Run this separately and you'll see it counts each time you run the sub.

Comment: @PortlandRunner This works just fine. But if I implement it into my code, it doesn't work. I guess the `Exit For` causes the problem.

Comment: If you removed `igOneVar = 0` from your code then it should keep counting each time you run your sub.  Otherwise, it will reset to zero at the beginning and increment to 1 in the `ElseIf` every time.

Comment: @PortlandRunner's suggestion should work... What changes did you make??

Comment: Just wrote a tiny code with the suggestions for the global variable and it works, but it doesn't work in my original code. But strange is, that he isn't able to find my variable at the beginnng even before my ElseIf.

Comment: That being the case, check your spelling... I'm not saying it's definietly the issue, but it might be....

Comment: There seems no error.... It is kinda frustrating. Everyting works, instead of saving the variable after it got incremented.

Comment: @JohnBustos I maybe found out why it isn't working, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I posted my comments to your latest solution... Also, what you are doing is posting additions to your questions, but posting them as answers... Please avoid from doing this in the future and simply appending onto your original question....

Comment: Thx for the advice @JohnBustos I just deleted my answers and updated the question. Your comment you posted below is attached to this comment.
QUOTE
Firstly, you are posting additions to your question - NOT solutions.. This is not the way to do it... Next, your issue is that you made the variable only scoped to the userform (you placed that declaration outside of the sub(), but in the code for the form). The problem is that you have the line Unload UserForm1 which ends the life of that variable. Put your variable in a separate module and that should fix your problem...

Comment: @JohnBustos I created a new module and put `Dim igOneVar as Integer` in it, I also deleted everythin within my forms code instead of the `igOneVar = igOneVar + 1`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I just stored my variable on an excel sheet. Not the best method, but I couldn't get anything else to work.

**Modul**

```
Sub ShowUserForm1() 

    UserForm1.Show 

End Sub
```

**Forms**

```
Private Sub Name_Click() 

Dim laufVar As Integer 
Dim igOneVar As Integer

igOneVar = Worksheets("Test").Range("A10").Value

If ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = 2 Then 
    For laufVar = 8 To 250 
        If ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = 2 Then 
            ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = "If" 
            Exit For 
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = 3 Then 
            ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = "ElseIf" 
            igOneVar = igOneVar + 1
            Worksheets("Test").Range("A10").Value = igOneVar
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next laufVar 
End If 

Unload UserForm1 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable igOneVar is public, its scope extends to the userform and it will be incremented when **Both** cell "B2"= 2 and cell "C2"=3 for the activesheet.

As long as both of these conditions are true igOneVar should increment to only 1 due to the EXIT FOR statement. Try setting a breakpoint as it seems the only problem is that the line that increments igOneVar is never executed.